# Can two rectangular matrices multiply to yield the Identity?

Tags: linear-algebra

For example, does there exist a 3x2 matrix and a 2x3 matrix such that the product is the 3x3 Identity matrix? If not, how would you go about proving that?

Comment: Do you know about row echelon form and pivot columns?

Comment: Try for the product of two matrices, one of which is $1\times 2$, the other $2\times 1$. That should get you on the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rank of the product of the two matrices is at most the rank of either of the individual matrices.

Answer (score 1):

One way to prove it: Let's say $A=(a_{ij})$ is $3 \times 2$ and $B$ is $2 \times 3$. Then \begin{equation}\text{Row}_i(AB)=\sum_{j=1}^{2}a_{ij} \text{ Row}_j(B),\end{equation} that is, row $i$ of the product is a linear combination of the rows of $B$ with coefficients from row $i$ of $A$. Since $B$ has only two rows, $AB$ has at most two linearly independent rows, while $I_3$ has three linearly independent rows.